# Causal graph based on data generation process

Tags: causality, causal-diagram

I am quite new to causal inference and want to try some methods for treatment effect estimation. For this purpose, I created a the following data generation process in Python:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10000
X3 = np.random.randint(1,4, n)
X2 = np.random.randint(1,11, n)

X1 = 5 * X2 + 3 * X3 + np.random.randint(-1,3, n)
X4 = 10 * X2 + np.random.randint(-2,5, n)

#treatment probability
propensity = np.where(X1 > 30, 0.8, 0.2)
T = np.random.binomial(1, propensity)

#treatment effect
tau = np.where(X2 > 5, 10,0) * T * (-1)

#define outcome
Y = 50 * X2 - 5 * np.sqrt(X1) + T*tau + np.random.randint(10,21, n)
```

For the generated data, I created the following graph:

[DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZlYT.png)

My question is: Since X2 (according to the data generation) does not influence the assignment of T but does have an influence on the treatment effect itself, is there an edge between X2 and T (X2->T) required?

Thank you very much!

Comment: No, an edge between X2 -> T shouldn't be written on your DAG (given the data set up). Drawing that arrow would imply that `propensity` depends on X1 AND X2. The effect of X2 on T fully flows through the X1 node (another way of seeing why we don't need the X2 -> T arrow).